# Hazelcast need to be connected as client in the existing cluster instead of member

Tags: wildfly, daemon, hazelcast, multicast, tcp

The changes which I made in server side:

```
@Bean(name = {"hazelcast"})
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName(integrationSettings.getHazelcastClusterGroupName())
        .setPassword(integrationSettings.getHazelcastClusterGroupPass());

    final ClientNetworkConfig clientNetworkConfig = new ClientNetworkConfig();
    clientNetworkConfig.addAddress("127.0.0.1:6701");
    clientConfig.setNetworkConfig(clientNetworkConfig);
    clientConfig.setInstanceName("INTEGRATION_INSTANCE");
    final String hazelcastEnterpriseLicenseKey = null;
    if (hazelcastEnterpriseLicenseKey != null) {
        clientConfig.setLicenseKey(hazelcastEnterpriseLicenseKey);
    }

    return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
}
```

I will be getting my groupname and password from my property file.

My client side code:

```
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();            

 clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName(hazelcastGroupName).setPassword(hazelcastGroupPwd);
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(serverAddress);
    hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

My error log:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:6701]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
            ... 37 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:6701]
            at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport.connectToCluster(ClusterListenerSupport.java:178)
            at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientClusterServiceImpl.start(ClientClusterServiceImpl.java:189)
            at com.hazelcast.client.impl.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.start(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:404)
            at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientManager.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClientManager.java:78)
            at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:72)
            at com.zafin.zrpe.integration.config.ZrpeIntegrationConfiguration.hazelcastInstance(ZrpeIntegrationConfiguration.java:85)
            at com.zafin.zrpe.integration.config.ZrpeIntegrationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7af6798e.CGLIB$hazelcastInstance$6(<generated>)
            at com.zafin.zrpe.integration.config.ZrpeIntegrationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7af6798e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$25f010cb.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
            at com.zafin.zrpe.integration.config.ZrpeIntegrationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7af6798e.hazelcastInstance(<generated>)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
            ... 38 more
```

I need to connect my hazelcast as a client, but this bean exception is failing the deployments. Is there is any other way of doing it?

Comment: The given error says that the Hazelcast Client failed to connect to a specified address - 127.0.0.1:6701. Do you want to connect to the separately running Hazelcast Member? Or the embedded one?

Comment: Do you have a member (server) running on `127.0.0.1:6701`? By default hazelcast runs on port 5701, so maybe you did a typo there?

Comment: @Nazar i already have one hazelcast client running in the cluster. I want to add another hazelcast in that cluster as a client and not as a member

Comment: @sertug yes im already having my hazelcast client running in this port. It will also accept this port. Port is not an issue i guess, because i even tried without specifying any port which will take the default one.

Comment: Just to clear a confusion: `addAddress()` method is for giving clients adresses of hazelcast members. That address List is the initial list of cluster addresses to which the client will connect. It is NOT the adress client will use for itself. So you need to give one of the members adress in the cluster in this method.

Comment: @sertug i have given the member address correctly. only the port number differs.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code  you are creating "Hazelcast-Client" on the server side and Client Side.  In the server side code , please create a hazelcast ServerMember instance by passing "Config" object and not "ClientConfig" more like

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() throws Exception {

    Config cfg = new Config();
    ...
    ...
    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
    return instance;
}
```

The the Hazelcast-client can connect to  the Hazelcast ServerMember. You also need to ensure the ServerMember is started before client can connect to it.

Comment: i need to connect the "hazelcast" as a client in server side code. so Iam using ClientConfig thing. If i use Config, it will be connecting as a member.

Comment: You can connect to Hazelcast Server from server-side code with hazelcast client, however  then a hazelcast server should be running  .. which in your case is not happening.  Please refer to Hazelcast topology section in reference manual.